# Exception when trying to return filtered Json objects array of different classes implementing the same interface

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

Here is a Play Framework (2.0.4, Java) controller action that aims to return a Json array containing various instances off classes implementing the same interface. I want to limit the Json fields to 4 (siren, nic, ncc, nccenr, my objects are french institutions).
I instantiate an ArrayList of Institutions that I fill with instances of different institutions filtered via EBean queries.

```
public static Result getCollectivitesList() {

    List<Institution> collectivites = new ArrayList<Institution>();

    collectivites.addAll(Commune.find.where().eq("departement", Departement.findByCode("44")).findList());
    collectivites.addAll(EtablissementPublic.find.all());
    collectivites.addAll(Departement.find.where().eq("code", 44).findList());
    collectivites.addAll(Region.find.where().eq("code", 52).findList());


    JsonContext jsonContext = Ebean.createJsonContext();
    JsonWriteOptions options = new JsonWriteOptions();
    options.setRootPathProperties("siren, nic, ncc, nccenr");
    String jsonString = jsonContext.toJsonString(collectivites, true, options);
    return ok(Json.parse(jsonString));

}
```

Individually, I can get only one kind of institution, but when I try to mix 2, 3 or 4 kinds, it throws an exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no HTTP Context available from here.

 play.mvc.Http$Context.current(Http.java:27)
 play.mvc.Controller.session(Controller.java:49)
 play.mvc.Controller.session(Controller.java:63)
 controllers.Authentication.isAuthenticated(Authentication.java:49)
 views.html.main$.apply(main.template.scala:92)
 views.html.errors.internalServerError$.apply(internalServerError.template.scala:30)
 views.html.errors.internalServerError$.render(internalServerError.template.scala:53)
 views.html.errors.internalServerError.render(internalServerError.template.scala)
 Global.onError(Global.java:21)
 play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:30)
 play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:159)
 play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115)
 akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318)
 play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113)
 akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626)
 akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197)
 akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:179)
akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:516)
 akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:259)
 akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
 akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1479)
 akka.jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

This exception is thrown when `JsonContext.toJsonString()` is called. I don't understand the problem, the relationship between polymorphism issues, the exception and the method that launch it.
Have you better ideas ?

**EDIT :**

I tried an alternative. I wrote a nested class :

```
private static class SimplifiedInstitution {
    String siren;
    String nic;
    String ncc;
    String nccenr;

    public SimplifiedInstitution(String siren, String nic, String ncc, String nccenr) {
        this.siren = siren;
        this.nic = nic;
        this.ncc = ncc;
        this.nccenr = nccenr;
    }
}
```

Instead of `jsonContext` things, i fill an ArrayList of SimplifiedInstitution in a foreach loop :

```
for (Institution institution : collectivites) {
        simplified.add(new SimplifiedInstitution(institution.siren(), institution.nic(), institution.ncc(), institution.nccenr()));
    }
```

And return Json like that :

```
return ok(Json.toJson(simplified));
```

The last line throws exactly the same exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a DIY trick : with the alternative try above, override the `toString()` method of `SimplifiedInstitution`:

```
public String toString() {
        return "{\"siren\":\"" + siren + "\",\"nic\":\"" + nic + "\",\"ncc\":\"" + ncc + "\",\"nccenr\":\"" + nccenr + "\"}";
    }
```

And rewrite the return statement of the controller action like that:

```
return ok(simplified.toString()).as("application/json");
```

This is not very satisfying and doesn't explain what was the cause of the problem, but it works.

PS: sorry for my English...